# Google playstore new permission policy for uploading Android App

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Google sent me mail stating:

> Your app needs to be using runtime permissions for us to complete the review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above and resubmit the declaration form.

- My App is already compiled with API 28. I submitted my app again stating my app is already compiled with 28, but Google rejected it again. Please help.

Comment: Full detail will be in the developer's Email id. It is basically because of the permissions used by some 3rd party libraries and your app has no use of that Permission.

Comment: This is the only detail I received by them on Mail. In am using few libraries whose entry is in build.gradle. How can I check their code for build version and permission implementation?

Comment: You have to check permissions by following this path app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

is your app's targetSdkVersion is also `>= 26` ?

Comment: Yes,
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

Answer (score 0):

app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml

Follow these paths for debug and release. If you find any Permission that causes you app rejection then you can follow the following steps to get rid of this situation.

1. Remove the library that adding this permission to your app.

   app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt

   use the above path to find out which library adding unwanted permission
2. If you want to retain this library then you need to add this permission to your original manifest and add a property to ignore it. 
   To ignore permission use code like this:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" 
   tools:node="remove" />`

Comment: None of the library uses any permission. Yes they are compiled with older versions of Android.

Comment: Then add a Privacy policy URL in your app as well as in store-listing on the playstore. And also keep in mind your privacy policy should clearly explain why these permissions used in the app. After that, you can publish again. Also, remove the old versions of the app from the Alpha and Beta testing channel if any.